# env variables are undefined in production (React App deployed with Heroku)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

I'm doing a project with React and Node, and I deployed it with Heroku,

Everything works well in development, but in production I don't have access to env variables,

For example, process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY is undefined in production, but in development it's OK,

Is it because I don't commit the .env file ? How can I get to .env values without commiting it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the settings of your app on Heroku.
[image]
Under the settings menu, you'll see `Reveal config vars`, click on it to add new ENV variables (with their keys and values) or see the ones previously added

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the env variables on your heroku server.

You need to go to your app in your heroku console, then click on the settings tab and then click on `Reveal Config Vars` button, this will give you the option to enter env vars enter a key and value for each one, for the key use the same as you used in your dev env like `REACT_APP_API_KEY` and so on.